# Import a binary log file in javascript

Tags: javascript, binary-data

I am creating a data-logger on a full featured LAMP server (actually it's a beaglebone with Debian). This data I want to import to a client side javascript to make some nice plots etc.

For the creation of the logging file I am running the following ANSI C Program in a cronjob every second:

```
struct md
{
    unsigned long int time;
    int ch0;
    int ch1;
    int ch2;
};

int main ()
{
  struct md mydata;
  /* assign values to mydata */
  FILE *fp0=fopen("out.bin","ab");
  fwrite(&mydata, sizeof(struct md), 1, fp0);
  fclose(fp0);
  exit (0);
}
```

As you might guess, the file out.bin get's soon quite big. Thats why I don't want to store it in ASCII.

I am sure, there is an easy way to do this, but I did not find a solution....

BTW, I am aware of the endianess problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will still need to make an ajax request to the file on the server.

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", "/myfile.png", true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
  var arrayBuffer = oReq.response; // Note: not oReq.responseText
  if (arrayBuffer) {
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.byteLength; i++) {
      // do something with each byte in the array
    }
  }
};

oReq.send(null);
```

[This document on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data) will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks justspamjustin, I hoped there is a more straightforward possibility.... now I'm struggling to put "// do something with each byte in the array" in a global variable, so that I can use it. somehow I that the problem is in "onload" but I cannot figure out how to do it.